# Duplicate validation errors in ComboBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, combobox, binding

I am trying to implement a ComboBox that supports CRUD, but I am struggling with a very peculiar issue[image: It says field is required]

Source code for the ComboBox:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Bailiffs,Mode=OneWay}" Name="bailiffComboBox"
          SelectedItem ="{Binding SelectedBailiff,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False}"
          SelectionChanged="BailiffComboBox_Selected"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          Text="{Binding SelectedBailiff.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEditable="{Binding Path=SelectedBailiff.IsEditing}"
          TextBoxBase.TextChanged="BailiffComboBox_TextChanged"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
          mah:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Съдия изпълнител">

        <ComboBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Gesture="Enter" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
            <KeyBinding Gesture="Escape" Command="{Binding CancelEditCommand}"/>
        </ComboBox.InputBindings>
        <ComboBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding NewCommand}" Header="Нов"/>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding EditCommand}" Header="Промяна"/>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" Header="Изтриване"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ComboBox.ContextMenu>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I am using a custom Validation library, that binds to property changes and validates changed properties based on defined rules. Works similar to FluentValidation. The viewModels that are supposed to validate implement INotifyDataErrorInfo(through ValidatedViewModel) by delegating to the aforementioned validator. The items in the ComboBox are ValidatedViewModels with a single property.

All of the errors come from the SelectedItem and Text property bindings of the ComboBox. When I remove SelectedItem binding, I get a single error. Otherwise I get 4-6 errors. Even if I disable validation on all bindings that have anything to do with this UserControl, I still get 3 validation errors. Also notice that the binding on SelectedItem has ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False.

Here is what I have tried:

- Disabling validation on all bindings - Reduces number of errors to 3
- Referencing the UserControl in a separate project - Works, shows a single error as expected
- Replacing the error template with a very simple one, as a proof that is not the cause - Same result
- Replacing ComboBox with TextBox - Shows single error, works fine
- Debugging the validation framework and checking returned error count, as well as count of property changed eventhandler calls - GetErrors always returns a single error and property changed is called only once, which is correct
- Debugging through WPF & .NET code trying to find a cause for the duplication of errors - Nothing

[image: 2]
The sources of the the binding errors. SelectedItem fails validation three times. Name, the property of the item view model that we are changing, fails once as expected

Comment: There is not enough information to tell the wrong or even to reproduce your observed behavior. But you could check your validation rules. Are they implemented properly? Do they return false errors? Have you added multiple instances of the same rule to the validator which would result in duplicate errors? Investigate. Setup an empty minimal project and make the data validate successfully first. Now deliberately introduce a data error. Can you observe the same behavior? If so, consider to implement data validation yourself. It's quite easy. Or/and contact the author of the library you are using.

Comment: `SelectedItem` might return `null`. Does this cause the errors? Why do you validate `SelectedItem`? Data or input validation is meant to validate data mutation performed by the user before this changes are persisted or processed. Selecting an item does not mutate data. It is the authors responsibility to populate the views with valid data that the user can interact with.

Comment: @BionicCode I have done all of the above. I know there isn't enough information, for which i am sorry. I just don't have anymore. I am the author of the validation library and I have tested all of the above suggestions. The validation always returns correct results. Why am I validating SelectedItem? I am not. Validation is disabled on that property as can be seen from the posted code. The validation errors persist if i replace SelectedItem binding with SyncWithCurrentItem.

Comment: I could swear I've read _"SelectedItem fails validation three times"_. Then how does SelectedItem relate to validation errors? _"Disabling validation on all bindings - Reduces number of errors to 3"_  Where are this three errors coming from? Are you sure your validator behaves correctly?

Comment: @BionicCode That is exactly what I am trying to figure out - Where are the errors coming from, when i have disabled validation for this property?! The validator is being called for SelectedItem, but I do not know why. The GetErrors method of the validator returns exactly one error in all of the above cases, but is being called many times - something that the WPF engine controls.

Comment: Can't blame it on the framework. It's client code. You're code. Seems like you're validation library is faulty. Validation rules must apply to a particular property not to all properties. Check it. You must be able to validate only specific properties no matter the binding's setting. The setting in the binding only enables that the error template is shown on validation errors. It doesn't enable or disable validation in general as this is done by the view model exclusively.

Comment: You must be able to place a break point in the validate method and step back down the call stack to see where this validation was triggered. This way you would recognize the undesired behaviour and fix it. GetErrors() is called by all binding targets. Maybe you have multiple bindings set on a single property.